# VBA - Selenium Chrome-Driver - Marcar combobox,

Tags: selenium-webdriver, excel-vba

Consegui encontrar um dos checkbox que quero marcar, porém ao tentar mandar o comando de click, ele da mensagem de erro dizendo que o objeto não é interativo. Como consigo marcar esses objetos?

```vb
    Dim fpm As Selenium.WebElement

    Set ch = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    
'    ch.AddArgument "--headless"
    ch.Start
    ch.Get "https://www.tesourotransparente.gov.br/consultas/transferencias-constitucionais-realizadas"
    
    Sleep (5000)
    
    Set fpm = ch.FindElementByXPath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[1]").Click
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salve, André!

Em primeiro lugar, um leve puxão de orelha: a pergunta está meio lacunosa. É melhor explicar direito o que você quer e qual é o seu problema. Alguém inclusive votou negativo em sua pergunta (o que eu não acho legal, porque dá para entender a pergunta e os votos negativos inibem a participação na comunidade).

Nem todo mundo tem tempo, como eu tive hoje, por isso, é importante explicar o status de forma clara e fazer perguntas objetivas para ter uma resposta boa.

Vamos à resposta.

**Ponto 1.** Há um erro no código, que é a linha `Set fpm = ch.FindElementByXPath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[1]").Click`. O método `FindElementByXPath()` retorna um objeto `WebElement` do Selenium; já o método `Click` de um `WebElement` clica o elemento e não retorna nada. Portanto, não dá para você atribuir o resultado do .Click para a variável `fpm`, que é do tipo `WebElement`.

Ou você apenas clica, sem atribuir o checkbox a variável nenhuma:

```
ch.FindElementByXPath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[1]").Click
```

Ou você atribui a checkbox à variável e depois clica:

```
Set fpm = ch.FindElementByXPath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[1]")
fpm.Click
```

**Ponto 2.** Na verdade, você não conseguiu referenciar o checkbox "fpm". Esse Xpath busca o primeiro checkbox da página; contudo, ao perguntar ao VBA qual o ID do objeto, veja o resultado:

```
?fpm.attribute("id")
searchbox_currentfolder_only
```

Ou seja: o que você encontrou aí foi, na verdade, o seguinte input, que fica no formulário de busca (a lupa no topo da página), e nem é exibido:

```
<input id="searchbox_currentfolder_only" class="noborder" type="checkbox" name="path" value="/clientes/ttransparente/ttransparente/consultas">
```

**Ponto 3.** EVITE buscar elementos com XPath. Sempre prefira usar ID ou nome, pois o XPath usa caminhos relativos que podem se quebrar se o responsável pela página mudar o leiaute. Por exemplo: mesmo que o seu XPath estivesse apontando para o checkbox correto, se na semana que vem o responsável pelo site adicionasse uma opção antes de FPM, seu programa já retornaria a checkbox errada. Usar a propriedade `name` ou `ID` sempre dá mais estabilidade (e na maioria das vezes é possível usar essas propriedades).

**Ponto 4.** Finalmente, vamos buscar o checkbox FPM.

Abri o Chrome, coloquei o checkbox aparente na tela, abri o painel de ferramentas de desenvolvedor (F12 ou Control + Shift + I), cliquei no checkbox FPM com o botão direito e escolhi "Inspecionar". A janela de `Elementos` vai automaticamente para o ponto do elemento clicado. É o seguinte elemento:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="P1_CX_TRANSFERENCIA_0" name="P1_CX_TRANSFERENCIA" value="3">
```

Percebido isso, em tese seria só usar um `ch.FindElementById("P1_CX_TRANSFERENCIA_0")`. Porém, há uma complicação: isso não vai retornar nada, porque o checkbox FPM está dentro de uma iFrame. Para manipular o elemento, é preciso avisar ao ChromeDriver para "entrar" na iFrame, usando o `ch.SwitchToFrame n` (no caso, 0, pois a iFrame que nos interessa é a primeira). Ao final, depois das interações que você quiser fazer, se estiver na mesma página, é importante voltar para o documento raiz, com a instrução `ch.SwitchToParentFrame`. Portanto, seu código ficaria assim:

```
Sub teste()
    Dim ch As Selenium.ChromeDriver
    Dim fpm As Selenium.WebElement, btnBuscar As Selenium.WebElement
    
    Set ch = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    
'    ch.AddArgument "--headless"
    ch.Start
    ch.Get "https://www.tesourotransparente.gov.br/consultas/transferencias-constitucionais-realizadas"
    ' Você não precisa do Sleep. No Selenium Basic, o timeout é o segundo parâmetro das funções Get e Find (coloquei ali embaixo 20000 milissegundos de exemplo).
    
    ch.SwitchToFrame 0
    
    Set fpm = ch.FindElementById("P1_CX_TRANSFERENCIA_0", 20000)
    Set btnBuscar = ch.FindElementById("btn-buscar")
    fpm.Click
    'Outras seleções e interações
    btnBuscar.Click
    'Interações para ler a resposta
    
    ch.SwitchToParentFrame

End Sub
```